# Use Foreign key in where clause in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models
1 is request and second is passed

I have a has_one association between requests and passed like this

**Request.rb**

```
 has_one :status
```

**status.rb**

`belongs_to :request`

in status I have a boolean field namely "passed"

Now I want to create a

```
scope :passed -> where(request.status.passed=true)
```

inside my requests model.

here are the migration/schema for my database

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.references :college, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user , foreign_key: true
      t.string :fullname
      t.string :email
      t.string :contact
      t.string :reason
      t.string :address_1
      t.string :address_2
      t.string :state
      t.string :city
      t.string :zipcode
      t.string :enrollment_no
      t.string :batch
      t.string :course
      t.text :extras


      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :requests , :email
  end
```

and this is my status migration

```
create_table :statuses do |t|
  t.references :request, foreign_key: true
  t.string :current_status, default: "Reviewing Application"
  t.boolean :passed , default: false
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
scope :passed, -> { joins(:status).where("statuses.passed = true") }
```

Took with adaptation from here: https://ducktypelabs.com/using-scope-with-associations/

This is the request model:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
  scope :passed, -> { joins(:status).where("statuses.passed = true") }
end
```

This is the status model

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
end
```

Migration for the requests table:

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Migration for the statuses table:

```
class CreateStatuses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :statuses do |t|
      t.boolean :passed, null: false, default: false
      t.references :request
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Please note that the `has_one :status` call must be declared before the scope definition or it won't work.

Comment: Can't join 'Request' to association named 'statuses'; perhaps you misspelled it?  
my association is has_one in request.rb so this error doesn't make sense

Comment: What's the "status" table called? And the model class? Also, could you post the request model to check the has_one association?

Comment: statuses is the name of table and Status is the name of ModelClass. let me make question more clear with some code

Comment: There was a typo in the table name ("status" instead of "statuses") in my response. I fixed and tested it and it works for me

Comment: still the same error cannot join request to association names status

Comment: I tried on a rails instance, this is working for me. Could you please post your DB schema for the 2 tables?

Comment: I posted the migrations of both the models

Comment: Based on the error you gave: "Can't join 'Request' to association named 'statuses'; perhaps you misspelled it?" it looks like you are using "joins(:statuses)" instead of "joins(:status)". Otherwise I don't see anything wrong in your code/schema

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: What rails version?

Comment: Rails 5.1 ruby 2.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152260/discussion-between-whites11-and-alaap-dhall).

Comment: I tried with rails 5.1 and it works just great. I'd love to troubleshoot this issue, if you want reach me on the chat.

Comment: ya sure, I too need some help